# Mercurial, define my own template/keyword: hostname

Tags: mercurial, keyword

I need a mercurail template/keyword "hostname" to get the name (or IP) of the computer where the repo is located. as far as i read the wiki, namely "Chapter 11. Customizing the output of Mercurial", hg help templates, and the web, I think it should be similar to the date keyword, dynamicly expanded. How can i define my own template/keyword?

Thank you verry much

Answer (score 2):

The following extension should do the trick:

```
from mercurial import templatekw

testedwith = "3.5"

_ipname = None

def showipname(repo, ctx, templ, **args):
  """:ipname: String. The hostname of the machine that the repository
  resides on."""
  import socket
  global _ipname
  if not _ipname:
    _ipname = socket.gethostname()
  return _ipname

def uisetup(ui):
  templatekw.keywords["ipname"] = showipname
```

Then use (say):

```
hg log -r . -T '{node|short} at {ipname}\n'
```

Note that the value of `socket.gethostname()` may depend on your internet connectivity. If you need the value in `/etc/hostname` or something else that identifies your machine, use that method instead.

To use an extension, put it in a file, say `ipnametempl.py` somewhere, then add the following lines to your `.hgrc`:

```
[extensions]
ipnametempl=/path/to/ipnametempl.py
```

This can be either your user/global `hgrc` or the `.hg/hgrc` in your repository (the latter if you only want to enable it for a specific repository). See `hg help hgrc` to find out where the user/global `hgrc` files are on your system.

Comment: Hi Reimer, sound's good. Where do i have to place this extension, somwhere in my repo, or somwhere in the place i have TortoiseHG installed on my Windwos?

Comment: @RolandSchmitz: I've updated my answer to explain this part.

Answer (score 0):

- Either the repository is local to your machine (then you can get the absolute path via `hg root`) and query the name via the normal system tools. You can embed those also in your templates:

  `$ hg log -r. --template="{branch}-{rev} from $(hostname) running debian $(cat /etc/debian_version)"
  trunk-22248 from MYHOSTNAME running debian 8.2`
- Or you know already the URL (remote path) in order to operate with it as you need to specify it as argument to hg pull/clone/outgoing/incoming
- If the remote URL is not explicitly specified on the command line it is specified in your .hgrc in the [path] section. When there is a remote repository at all, then usually a `default = URL` is defined there.

If you need the URL printed, then install hooks for clone, pull and push (and maybe outgoing and incoming) which prints the $URL as available in those hooks - or maybe just the changegroup hook. Check http://hgbook.red-bean.com/read/handling-repository-events-with-hooks.html#sec:hook:changegroup and `hg help config`.